# Geany debugger installation

Tags: 18.04, plugins, debugging, geany

I want to add new plugins for debugging to Geany. But I have the following problem:

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
> may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  geany-plugins :
> Depends: geany-plugin-git-changebar (>= 1.36+dfsg-1~16.04) but it is
> not going to be installed
> Depends: geany-plugin-workbench (>= 1.36+dfsg-1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

What can I do to install it?

I use: `sudo apt install geany-plugins`

Comment: Where I can see it? I'm new to linux

Comment: I receive this command :  geany-plugin-workbench: command not found

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update `geany-plugin-workbench`.

[1.36 is scheduled for Ubuntu Focal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/geany-plugin-workbench) = 20.04 so not available for Ubuntu users from a normal install (ie. `apt`).

[Source installation](https://plugins.geany.org/downloads.html) from git:

> **Download directly from version control**
>
> You can pull the sources for Geany-Plugins directly from version control as well. To do this, just clone the Git repository like this:
>       git clone git://github.com/geany/geany-plugins.git geany-plugins
>
> Build and install all plugins:
>
> ```
> ./autogen.sh # Note this already runs ./configure
>
> make && make install
> ```

Comment: I still have a problem with autogen.sh. When i try to start it by ./autogen.sh i receive this information: ./autogen.sh: intltoolize: not found
I can't find in google what is it